# What segment of memory are functions stored in?

Tags: c++, c

Global variables are stored in data, dynamically allocated variables are stored in heap, etc. Where are functions (such as main, other functions in main.c, printf, etc) stored? Is it in the code segment?

Comment: Research makes you a better programmer.

Comment: On the stack, yo. hence why recursion can eat up your whole stack, thus causing a stack overflow...

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Side note: you'll save yourself a lot of grief if you stop thinking of C and C++ as the same language.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have any concept of segments, this is an implementation detail of the tool chain and there is no standard that specifies where they are stored.

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought I was reading pure gold, but then I came to the end! Dangit!

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate is a duplicate.   None of the answers to that question answer this question and the duplicate it is a duplicate of is about undefined behaviour and not about memory segments at all..

Answer (score 1):

This is not a C or C++ question. Neither of those ISO standards mandate anything *like* how different things are allocated to memory segments.

In fact, the whole idea of segments is irrelevant to the standards since they dictate the behaviour of a C or C++ "virtual machine" - they tend to dictate *behaviour* rather than *how* the behaviour is achieved.

However, *if* you're in an implementation that has a code segment, that's the most likely place where code would be stored :-)

Comment: This is typically called the "text segment".